# passing a function from a class with the scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm writing a javascript project.. and I have a need to paste a function from a class object, to a different function and to execute it from the other function. the problem is that the scope of the function changes, in the function I use `this` and since the scope changes, this fails. is there any way to forward this function with preserving the scope?

I wrote an example to demonstrate the problem I'm having

```
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');

class a {
  b = 5;

  getB() {
    return this.b;
  }
}

const obj = new a();
const aa= obj.getB;

appDiv.innerHTML = aa();
```

so when I run aa() it fails because `this.b` is undefined.

how do I resolve this?

I also created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hjzedd?file=index.js

Comment: `const aa = obj.getB.bind(obj)`.

Comment: No, it fail because aa = a.b = 5, so you try to call a number.

Comment: Another possible way could be: const aa = () => obj.getB();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `This` with functions

Within a function, the value of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) depends on how the function is called.

If in [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), then the value of `this` is `undfined`. If not in strict mode, `this` will default to the global object, which is window in a browser.

### The issue

When extracting out the function into the new variable, the original object is lost.

### Use bind to solve the issue

Using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) will allow you to set the `this` value.

```js
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');

class a {
  b = 5;

  getB() {
    return this.b;
  }
}

const obj = new a();
const aa= obj.getB.bind(obj);

appDiv.innerHTML = aa();
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```